# cryptsetup "command not found"

Tags: debian, terminal, command, luks, cryptsetup

Hey guys i am on a Debian following this guide
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upOqR4HPi60
and when i type in this command

```
cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/YourDeviceName /keyfile
```

i get

```
cryptsetup: command not found
```

Ive been searching around and i can't find anyone with a problem like this. Also something that might have something to do with it is that in /etc/crypttab it says discard at the end. does that mean its disabled maybe?

Answer (score 4):

In Debian this utility is stored as `/sbin/cryptsetup`, thus it's supposed to be available only to the root user.

Use the full path, e.g.

`/sbin/cryptsetup`

or run it via sudo:

`sudo cryptsetup`

or add it to PATH, e.g.

`PATH="/sbin:$PATH" cryptsetup`

Lastly you might be missing the package though it seems very unlikely: `sudo apt install cryptsetup-bin` will fix it.